# Why do I get a black screen?

Tags: python, pygame

Problem is that all I can see is a black screen when run, think the problem is to do with blitting but not 100% sure

```
#IMPORTING PYGAME
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

FPS = 60
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400), 0, 32)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

#DIRECTIONS
LEFT = 1
DOWN = 3
UP = 7
RIGHT = 9
#SPEED OF MOVEMENT
MOVESPEED = 4
#COLOURS
WHITE = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

#DRAWING ASSETS/SPRITES
player1 = (windowSurface, pygame.Rect(200, 200, 20, 20), GREEN, UP)
player1.blit(pygame.surface.blit, (200), area=None, special_flags = 0)

player2 = (windowSurface, pygame.Rect(100, 100, 20, 20), GREEN, DOWN)
#player2 = (pygame.Surface.blit(, windowSurface))

barricade1 = {windowSurface:pygame.Rect(50, 5000, 20, 20), :GREEN, :UP}
#barricade1(pygame.Surface.blit(, windowSurface))

barricade2 = {windowSurface:pygame.Rect(250, 250, 20, 20), :GREEN, :DOWN}
#barricade2(pygame.Surface.blit(, windowSurface))

#ball = {'rect':pygame.Rect(200, 200, 20, 20), 'color':GREEN, 'dir':UPDOWNLEFTRIGHT}
#ball(pygame.Surface.blit(, windowSurface))

#SPRITE GROUPS
players = [player1, player2]
barricades = [barricade1, barricade2]
ball = [ball]

windowSurface.fill(WHITE)

pygame.display.update()
fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Your `WHITE` Variable is wrong. That is Black in RGB Format. White is (255,255,255)

**2.** You are filling the screen and immediately after that you update it.

First fill the screen and **THEN** you can draw your players on top.

```
windowSurface.fill(WHITE)

#Do drawing here

pygame.display.update()
```